# Disable the UseGCOverheadLimit in CentOS

Tags: java, linux, garbage-collection

I need to disable the GC Overhead limit in my `CentOS` server. The reason for this is to temporarily prevent `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` exceptions.

But i'm a zero at Linux + Java systems and don't have any clue on how to run this command line: `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`

Comment: Sorry, this question doesn't really make much sense. You need to pass that flag to whatever Java **program** you're running and you haven't said what it is or how it's run.

Comment: i'm hosting a web application developed in java, i didn't do the development and my client has lost contact with the developers. He said that lately when they try to export data to Excel (very large database) it gives a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded exceptions` error. So i've search arround and found out that that exception can be disabled. So that's what i'm trying to do. The application in running on a CentOS machine with Apache Tomcat 5.0.30

Comment: This is a rare error which can only occur if you have hardly sufficient memory. Most likely, it's more effective to increase the memory given to Tomcat.

Comment: Your clients needs a host that actually knows how to manage Java apps then. How to wrangle the production environment Tomcat isn't really a developer issue in this setup.

Comment: @millimoose i'm hosting this web application temporarily for testing purposes - i'm just a developer not a Sys Admin ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to pass it to the JVM as an argument. You say your hosting a webapp in Apache Tomcat. You can set the environment variable `CATALINA_OPTS` to equal `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`. You'll have to do this in the script that actually starts tomcat if your running it as a service, and in fact the Tomcat script for CentOS probably has a `CATALINA_OPTS` variable in it that you can add to or set.

That being said, eliminating the ability for the garbage collector to throw an OutOfMemoryError (OOME) due to overhead may not fix the problem. OOME due to overhead basically means the program was not making any useful progress due to the GC operations taking a lot of time. This can happen when free memory is very low and lots of full GC passes have to be made frequently. If you disable the error, its possible the program will simply become unresponsive before finally actually running out of memory in the heap at some undefined point in the future which will still cause an OOME to be thrown for heap space instead of overhead.

A better solution would be instead to increase the amount of memory Tomcat is allowed to use by setting using the -Xmx argument (again passed in via `CATALINA_OPTS`). `-Xmx2g` would set max heap to 2 GiB for instance.

Comment: hi @Dev thanks for your help. I've managed to resolve my issue setting the -Xmx value to 2GB :)